# Pandas filter by substrings from two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that are as follows:

Dataframe `df1`:

```
    Rep
0   ec21b_AI_154OH
1   m2010_AI_066UW
2   20wh1_DS_416FC
```

Dataframe `df2`:

```
    Address     FirstPart   SecondPart
0   address13   m2010       066UW
1   address22   2020e       999GV
2   address26   2020c       513DT
3   address35   evd18       874GO
4   address36   ep21b       986CG
5   address493  20wh1       416FC
6   address628  ec21b       154OH
```

I want to add an `Address` column in dataframe `df1` using pandas, so that it looks as follows:

```
    Rep             Address
0   ec21b_AI_154OH  address628
1   m2010_AI_066UW  address13
2   20wh1_DS_416FC  address493
```

For every row in `df2`, I can search for matches in `df1`, and put the address.
However, is there a better way to do it?

My minimum working example is as follows:

```
for First, Second, Add in zip(list(df2['FirstPart']),list(df2['SecondPart']),list(df2['Address'])):
    condition = df1['Rep'].str.contains(First) & df1['Rep'].str.contains(Second)
    df1.loc[condition,"Address"] = Add
```

**Note:** It is not necessary to find `_` as a delimiter, and there can be other delimiters as well.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the two part to use for a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) (here with named capturing groups, although optional if you use the `left_on`/`right_on` parameters or `merge`):

```
out = df1.join(
 df1['Rep']
 .str.extract(r'^(?P<FirstPart>[^_]+).*?(?P<SecondPart>[^_]+)$')
 .merge(df2, how='left')['Address']
)
```

output:

```
              Rep     Address
0  ec21b_AI_154OH  address628
1  m2010_AI_066UW   address13
2  20wh1_DS_416FC  address493
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just loop trought the both columns:

Those are you dfs, on the first df just add the new column Address:

```
 import pandas as pd
df_dict_1 = {
    'Rep':['ec21b_AI_154OH', 'm2010_AI_066UW', '20wh1_DS_416FC'],
    
    'Address': [None, None, None]
        
   
        }

df_dict_2 = {
    'Address':['address13', 'address22', 'address26', 'address35', 'address36',\
                            'address493', 'address628' ],
    
    'FirstPart':['m2010', '2020e', '2020c', 'evd18', 'ep21b',\
                            '20wh1', 'ec21b' ],
    
    'SecondPart':['066UW', '999GV', '513DT', '874GO', '986CG',\
                            '416FC', '154OH' ],
   
        }




df1 = pd.DataFrame(df_dict_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df_dict_2)
```

And loop trought the second one:

```
rep_list = list(df1.Rep)


for x in range(df2.shape[0]):
  
    first_part = df2.FirstPart.iloc[x]
    second_part = df2.SecondPart.iloc[x] 

    rep = ''.join([x for x in rep_list if first_part in x and  second_part in x])
    adress = df2.Address.iloc[x]

    for x in range(len(df1.Rep)):
        if rep ==df1.Rep[x]:
            df1.Address.iloc[x] = adress
```

Output:

```
    Rep             Address
0   ec21b_AI_154OH  address628
1   m2010_AI_066UW  address13
2   20wh1_DS_416FC  address493
```